# Black screen when playing video using GMImagePickerController

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
- (void)assetsPickerController:(GMImagePickerController *)picker didSelectAsset:(PHAsset *)asset{

self.videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:asset.localIdentifier];

NSLog(@"The value of URL is %@:",self.videoURL);

[self playVideo];

[picker.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)playVideo{

self.playerVC = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];

self.playerVC.moviePlayer.contentURL = self.videoURL;
self.playerVC.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
[self.playerVC.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 100, 320, 385)];
[self.view addSubview:self.playerVC.moviePlayer.view];

[self.playerVC.moviePlayer play];
}
```

After choosing video from Camera Roll, I intend to play it on app but a black screen appears as shown:

[image]

What's wrong with my code? Thanks!

Comment: Does your video playing?

Answer (score 1):

Here MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't get your video url. You should check that video url is available or not.
Here you are getting video url in background thread

`[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:kNilOptions
                           completionHandler: ^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info)  {
     self.videoURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
}];`

Till you get video url, MPMoviePlayerViewController code get executed.

To overcome this issue first you should get video url and if url is available call MPMoviePlayerViewController code to play video.

Comment: url appears when NSLog but the screen is still black

Comment: Are you using the code which you depicted in question?

Comment: I check out your code. Its working, i think issue is in your url.

Comment: I have passed my video url and its working. (- (void)playVideo is working).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80893/discussion-between-arvin-sanmuga-rajah-and-rajesh-maurya).